# Limit SQLServer Full text search to top 3 releavent answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I am a SQL newbie sorry if this is a simple thing

My data in sql is like this

**My DATA:**

```
Content    sl.no
KTUU Alaskas News Source Alaskas Top News Storm Watch Weather Politics Sports Health Business Headlines 16419
Lawn Care Business Service Providers Lawn Care Business Information Lawn Mowing Companies Lawn Care Directory   17113
Hydrophilic polyurethane foams medical consumer personal care cosmetics agricultural products Rynel     17183
Care Patient Care Product Manufacturer  17752
Bartlett Tree Experts Leader Residential Commercial Tree Care Services  17890
Safe Earth Lawn & Garden Care   17920
Carolina Outdoor Care Inc   17972
Glenwood Autism Behavioral Health us difference 17997
Mental Health North Central Alabama 18092
East Alabama Mental Health  18093
Jacksonville Mental Health  18094
Mental Health Assn-Madison Cty  18095
Baptist Health Ctr  18136
Mental Health Wellness Information Community Counseling Services    18150
Dayspring Behavioral Health 18162
Daysprings Behavioral Health    18164
Families Outpatient Mental Health Counseling Services   18167
Families Outpatient Mental Health Counseling Services   18168
Health Resources Of Arkansas    18170
Mental Health Council Of Ar 18172
```

If I run the following query

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM TABLE_NAME where FREETEXT(content,'health care')
```

> I get the first three rows rather then the first three row which are
>   closer to the answer

How to get the first three most relevant Query.

And Can the query be fast as like the previous one

Comment: What will that something be it can't be content it should be something like rank or something but how to do that so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FREETEXTTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) instead of [FREETEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx). This will give you a result set of matches including a `Rank` which you can order by.Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245.aspx) for more insight

```
SELECT TOP 3 RANK, [KEY]
FROM FREETEXTTABLE(TABLE_NAME,content,'health care') 
ORDER BY RANK DESC
```

Join by `KEY` to get the columns from the original table.

```
SELECT TOP 3 TABLE_NAME.*
FROM FREETEXTTABLE(TABLE_NAME,content,'health care') as fullTextResults
join TABLE_NAME on fullTextResults.[KEY] = TABLE_NAME.Id
ORDER BY fullTextResults.RANK DESC
```